# How to differentiate between "some text" and 'some text'?

Tags: php, string

If I have two variables:

```
$v1 = "some text";
$v2 = 'some test';
```

Is it possible to recognize which string variable was defined using single quote and which one using double quotes?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that you would need to do so?

Comment: I though there is because php recognizes these strings. If string has single quotes it will not try to parse for variables.

Comment: So what. Variable substitution is out of your scope. If you want templating then use templating.

Comment: The reason I ask is that at job interview I was told there is and it was bugging me, because I did not now how. But i guess interviewers also make mistakes.

Comment: I'd ask the interviewer how next time when I don't know the answer :)

Comment: It's perfectly easy to do.... you look at your source code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Nor should you have to care.

Answer (score 1):

**No, there is no way to do that.** Once the string is assigned, it's done, you can't check it later.

---

However, if you really really really want, you can have a array that stores how the string got assigned but you have to update that array yourself. Like this:

```
$v1 = "some text";
$info['v1'] = true;
$v2 = 'some test';
$info['v2'] = false;
```

Here, you can later check the value of $info array. If it's true, you did it by double quote otherwise single quote. *However, there is no practical use of this thing that I can understand. It's totally useless.*

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do so, and it doesn't make sense to try and find out.

What about strings read from a file or user input? What about a double-quoted string appended to a single-quoted string? What quoting style would result? What kind of quotes surround an integer when it's cast to a string?

Answer (score 1):

Uhm. If your task was to find that out through statical analysis, not runtime analysis (which is impossible), you probably should use the [Tokenizer](http://php.net/Tokenizer) and analyze the token stream of the file and see whether the appropriate `T_VARIABLE` is assigned a `'"'` or a `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`. The former will happen, if a variable is interpolated, the latter if it is not. If you want to distinguish between `"` and `'`, not between interpolated/not interpolated you should check the first character of the `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` against `'` and `"`.

Though I am very sure, that nobody wanted to know this in an interview. The Tokenizer is really high stuff, that rarely somebody knows about, it won't be in a standard interview ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see which string was created with which literal. But there are some differences in how the literals are interpreted:

http://dev.fyicenter.com/faq/php/php_string_operation.php